# VueJS with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, vue.js, vue-component

guys, my project using django and vueJS. I want to sign files with digital signatures. One of my cabinets is full django, so there i did it with jQuery scripts. Now i want import this script to my vue code. So user could click button and it will call signFile function. I created few script tags in vue component, using created.

```
  let es6Promise = document.createElement('script')
  es6Promise.setAttribute('src', '/static/etf/js/signing/es6-promise.min.js')
  document.head.appendChild(es6Promise)

  let ieEventlistnerPolyfill = document.createElement('script')
  ieEventlistnerPolyfill.setAttribute('src', '/static/etf/js/signing/ie_eventlistner_polyfill.js')
  document.head.appendChild(ieEventlistnerPolyfill)

  let firefoxCadespluginAsync = document.createElement('script')
  firefoxCadespluginAsync.setAttribute('src', '/static/etf/js/signing/firefox_cadesplugin_async.js')
  document.head.appendChild(firefoxCadespluginAsync)

  let cadespluginApi = document.createElement('script')
  cadespluginApi.setAttribute('src', '/static/etf/js/signing/cadesplugin_api.js')
  document.head.appendChild(cadespluginApi)

  let code = document.createElement('script')
  code.setAttribute('src', '/static/etf/js/signing/Code_js.js')
  document.head.appendChild(code)

  let signFileScript = document.createElement('script')
  signFileScript.setAttribute('src', '/static/etf/js/signing/signFile.js')
  document.head.appendChild(signFileScript)
```

I created button. signFile function is in signFile.js. So how can i make event on click to call this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include `signFile.js` in `index.html`. After this your functions will be available on the `window` object.

To use a method exposed by `signFile.js` you can write something like this

```
window.SignMethod(args)
```

inside a callback from a vuejs handler.

Comment: it says, window.signing(id) is not a function